# how to transfer data beetwen controller in the pattern MVC (PHP)

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, interface-implementation

i'm using the MVC pattern, to implement a section, in my site, to buy the articles exposed. I have, however , a great problem to implement this section and, in particular, to exchange data between my controllers, and to use this data in all the views.

At now, i tried two solution to pass this data between Controllers:

- the first is to create, at the top of the code of my controller, some object of my Model classes, that can be modified from all the switch branch, (and so from all the section of my controller). I can't understand why, passing from a view to another, always trough the same controller, my object is resetted and take to null.
- the second, a not too much usefull solution, is to use a great array, passed from a view to another (from a switch branch of the same controller, to another branch), trough a form, or, however, superglobal variables.

I show you the views and the code:

The first picture is the login-view; the user is not logged-in, has already specified the formats in which he wants to receive the object and has to log in.

http://i60.tinypic.com/2nq9rfd.jpg

The second pictures is the view after that user is logged in. All user and objects data are obtained trough query, but i need to remeber the formats in which the user wants to receive the pictures!

The formats... the payment method selected, and so on.

http://i61.tinypic.com/2v2xkt3.jpg

The code..

My MVC pattern consist in one index.php (the only point of access to my site) that instantiate an object of class "X"-Controller that popolates my master.php.

THe master.php is a dynamic page popolate under convenience from my controllers, that instatiantes all variables and object variables to compose the view requested.

In particular, this the code of the section for buying:

The controller

(complete (relative) url = /index.php?page=works&subpage=payment&imageID=00000001)

```
class WorksController
{
    public static $counter = 0;

    public function __construct(&$request, &$session)
    {
        self::$counter++;
        $this -> handle_input($request, $session);

    }

    private function handle_input(&$request, &$session)
    {
        //It create a new Album (class RaccoltaImmagini), that include all pictures (class Immagine) that have to be sell
        if(!isset($raccoltaImmagini))
        {

            $raccoltaImmagini = PicturesCollectionConstructor::buildNewCollection("AllPictures"); 

        }

        if(!isset($riepilogoOrdine))
        {
            //IT creates a new object (class Ordine) that include all infos to complete and to manage the transaction
            $riepilogoOrdine = new Ordine(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

        }

        if(!isset($userOBJ))
        {
            //It creates a new object that rappresent the user logged in and all the data associated (like credential, name, adress, credit card..)
            $userOBJ = new AuthenticatedUser(null, null, null, null, null, null,null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        switch($request["subpage"]) 
        {
            default: include("PHP/view/content-not-found.php");
                     break;

            case "payment": //This part of the Controller manage the view to select the payment method:             
                            //if the user is not logged in, the view charge the secondary form for the login
                            //else the view show a short recap about the options already selected, and the method of payments registered to choose


                            if(isset($request["imageID"]))  //Step 1 - The authenticated user has to choose the payment's method
                            {
                                if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) && $_SESSION[ "loggedIn"]) 
                                {
                                    if( isset($session["username"]) && isset($session["password"]))//User authenticated
                                    {   
                                        //It show which formats have been selected (it store an array of booleans, where array[$i] is true if the format is requested)                                          
                  $formati = $riepilogoOrdine -> getAllReservedFormats();


                                        //It initialize the object that represent the authenticated User
                                        $userOBJ = UserConstructor::buildUser($session["username"], $session["password"]); 

                                        //It initialize the object that represent the pictures that has to be sell
                                        $describedOBJ = $raccoltaImmagini -> getImagesByID($request["imageID"]);

                                        //- It update, newly, the information about the order:

                                        //-- It associates the user-id to ther order
                                        $riepilogoOrdine -> setUserID($userOBJ -> getID()); 

                                        //-- it associates the image-id to ther order
                                        $riepilogoOrdine -> setArticleID($describedOBJ -> getID());

                                        //-- it associates the partial import to ther order
                                        $riepilogoOrdine -> setTotalImport($describedOBJ -> getPrice());



                                        $style = "PHP/view/TransactionsStyle.php";
                                        $header = "PHP/view/Header.php";
                                        $loginFormContent = "PHP/view/loggedUserMenu.php";
                                        $slideshow=null;
                                        $works = "PHP/view/Works.php";
                                        $preview250="PHP/view/preview250.php";
                                        $SecondaryLoginForm = null;
                                        $summaryPayments = "PHP/view/summaryPayments.php";
                                        $ToPay = "PHP/view/ToPay.php";
                                        $footer="PHP/view/footer.php"; 


                                        include("master.php");
                                    }
                                }
                                else //Step 0 - The user is not still logged in
                                {

                                    //It initialize the object that represent the pictures that has to be sell 
                                    $describedOBJ = $raccoltaImmagini -> getImagesByID($request["imageID"]);


                                    //- It update the information about the order:

                                    //-- it associates the partial import to ther order
                                    $riepilogoOrdine -> setTotalImport($describedOBJ -> getPrice());

                                    //-- It associates to the order the formats select (obtained trough a previous submit) 
                                    if(isset($_REQUEST["formats"]))
                                    {
                                        $formats = array();
                                        $formats = $_REQUEST["formats"];


                                        if(isset($formats[0])) //online formats
                                        {
                                            $riepilogoOrdine -> setOnlineFormat(True); 
                                        }

                                        if(isset($formats[1])) //gallery1 format
                                        {
                                            $riepilogoOrdine -> setGallery1Format(True); 
                                        }

                                        if(isset($formats[2])) //gallery2 format
                                        {
                                            $riepilogoOrdine -> setGallery2Format(True);
                                        }

                                    }


                                    //It show which formats have been selected (it store an array of booleans, where array[$i] is true if the format is requested)                                          
                                    $formati = $riepilogoOrdine -> getAllReservedFormats();

                                    $style = "PHP/view/TransactionsStyle.php";
                                    $header = "PHP/view/Header.php";
                                    $loginFormContent = "PHP/view/LoginFormContent.php"; 
                                    $works = "PHP/view/Works.php";
                                    $preview250="PHP/view/preview250.php";

                                    $SecondaryLoginForm="PHP/view/SecondaryLoginFormContent.php";
                                    $ToPay = "PHP/view/ToPay.php";



                                    $footer="PHP/view/footer.php"; 
                                    include("master.php");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                include("PHP/view/content-not-found.php");
                            }

                            break;
 [...] //other code omitted
} //swith closure
```

The view

```
<?php $IMGid = $describedOBJ -> getID(); ?>
<!-- It contains a recap for every step of transaction -->
<div id="Riepilogo">  

<!-- It stores the information about the transaction -->
<div id="Transazione">
    <?php if(isset ($SecondaryLoginForm)) include($SecondaryLoginForm); ?> <!-- Step 0: User is not logged in -->

    <?php if(isset ($summaryPayments)) include($summaryPayments); ?> <!-- Step 1: User logged in and selection of payment's method -->

    <?php if(isset ($shipments)) include($shipments); ?> <!-- Step 2: selection of the shipment's method -->

</div>

<!-- It contains a recap about the pictures to buy -->
<div id="RiepilogoVisuale">

    <!-- close the window -->
    <button name="chiudi" type="button" id="closingButton" onclick="javascript:chiudi();">Chiudi</button>

    <!-- It contains details about the pictures -->
    <article id="descrizioneImmagine">
        <header id="TitleAuthor">
            <h1><?php echo($describedOBJ -> getTitolo());?>   by  </h1>
            <h2><?php echo($describedOBJ -> getAutore());?></h2>
        </header>

        <section id="previewImmagine">
            <img src="<?php echo($describedOBJ -> getPreview850());?>" alt="<?php echo($describedOBJ->getDescrizione());?>"> 
        </section>

        <!-- information about price, formats etc -->
        <section id="riepilogoAcquisto">
            <h1>Riepilogo acquisto:</h1>

            <div id="formatiIMG">
                <h2>Formati Selezionati</h2>
                <ul>

                    <?php
                        if(isset($formati["online"]) && $formati["online"]) 
                        {?>
                            <li><?php  echo("Formato online (High Res.)")?></li>
                    <?php }
                        if(isset($formati["gallery1"]) && $formati["gallery1"]) 
                        {?>
                            <li><?php echo("Formato galleria piccolo(90x160 cm)")?></li>
                    <?php }
                        if(isset($formati["gallery2"]) && $formati["gallery2"]) 
                        {?>
                            <li><?php echo("Formato galleria grande (100x200 cm)")?></li>
                    <?php }?>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="AdditionalInfo">
                <section id="prezzo">
                    <h2>Prezzo:</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo($riepilogoOrdine -> getTotalImport())?>€</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

                <section id="spedizione">
                    <h2>Metodo di spedizione:</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Corriere Espresso</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>

            </div>

        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

I hope you could help me, thank you all for your patience

EDIT: i added the code of my index.php, that calls all the controllers

```
  <?php 
  //include directives for all the controllers
  //code omitted


Dispatcher::dispatch($_REQUEST);

class Dispatcher
{


public static function dispatch(&$REQUEST)
{

    session_start();

    if(isset($REQUEST["page"]))
    {
        switch($REQUEST["page"]) 
        {

            default: 
                    include("PHP/view/content-not-found.php");
                    break;

            //code from other controllers omitted
            case "works": 
                    new WorksController($REQUEST, $_SESSION);
                    break;

        }

    }

}



}

  ?>
```

Comment: "I can't understand why, passing from a view to another, always trough the same controller, my object is resetted and take to null." If you have a Front Controller, check that it is not re-initializing your object on every new page request.

Comment: Probably you are right.... is stupid by me but in effect in the index.php there is a call of static method that calls and initialize all the Controllers... So, every new call to index.php, if i'm right, make a new static method and new controllers, different all from the others... The question now is... how to solve? A great array passed through superglobal? Or what else???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if could be the perfect solution, but i thought to the role of $_SESSION array for the user.. The data that i have to store and exchange between controllers, are data related only to the user and necessaries to proceed to the next view... So I used $_SESSION["otherData"] to store the content of my summary array:

```
 //It stores the data on the server, first than write them to the Database
 $_SESSION["otherData"] = $riepilogoOrdine; 

 //where riepilogoOrdine track     
 //the information, obtained from the user, about the order
```